# How to bind a Grid in WPF when using MVC?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, model-view-controller, data-binding

I know a way to do MVC binding of one string to one TextBox. That's how it can be done:

**C#:**

```
namespace WpfApplication4
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = Model;
        }

        public ModelClass Model = new ModelClass();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Model.Output += "Setting New Output! ";
        }

        public class ModelClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            string _output;
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = 
                         delegate { };    
            public string Output
            {
                get { return _output; }
                set { _output = value;
                    PropertyChanged(this, 
                                    new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Output"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" VerticalAlignment="Top"  
                Name="button1"  Click="button1_Click" />
        <TextBox  VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  
                  Name="textBox1" Text="{Binding Path=Output}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

But I can't find a way to bind a two-dimensional array (or List) to a Grid or DataGrid. Can you help me with it? I couldn't find a working example on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a **DataGrid** to display your two-dimensional array, assuming you can store your data as a `List<ColumnData>` where ColumnData is a class with one property per table column.

The WPF SDK contains a DataGrid, and there are several data grids from vendors available that have additional features.

Comment: Columns can either be auto-generated, or you can explicitly define which fields in which order. Check out the DataGrid samples for some more information on how to get started.

Answer (score 1):

if you wanna bind data to a datagrid you should be read something about the following.

> ICollectionView,  BindingListCollectionView

if you have somekind of collection you simply set the itemssource.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyCollection, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Collection types are mostly ObservableCollection or DataSet/DataTable. if your collection supports editing and so on, you can do it with the datagrid.